# How do I load content from a PHP file (and executing the script) from another PHP file?

Tags: php, scripting, content-management-system, echo

I have a PHP script (index.php) that changes the page shown depending on the query part of the URL (using GET). All the links in the page access different "pages" using `?page=pageName` and the index.php script loads HTML from text files accordingly (echoing it to the screen).

So, if a user goes to `index.php?page=about`, my PHP script loads a file called `about.php` and echoes it in a view container in the browser.

**However, I have a big problem**: The content I'm loading has PHP scripts inside it, but those scripts aren't executed when echoed using the `index.php` script. That makes it impossible for me to load a page that contains, say, a directory listing pulled from a MySQL database.

So basically, I want to know if there is any way that I can echo a PHP file onto a page but execute the PHP code inside the file as well.

For clarity, I have attached an annotated screenshot that describes what I mean:

**EDIT:** Here's the link:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use if statements to include('about.php') in index.php, and put the echo statements inside about.php.  If this doesn't work, please post code examples.

```
if( $_REQUEST['someQuery'] == 'about' )
{
     include('about.php');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It works perfectly! As @symcbean pointed out, my question wasn't very clear at times, but you figured it out. :)
Kudos!

Comment: But do be aware of what happens when someone tries to access index.php?page=../../../../../etc/passwd or similar

Comment: I would only use this solution as part of a learning exercise or private website.  There is a lot of room for sql injection attacks using this method!

Answer (score 1):

Using `include()` will include the content of another PHP script and execute it. If that other PHP script contains functions that produce the output then you will need to invoke them separately.

Comment: If I had enough rep points, I would mark this as helpful :)
However, I accepted @Toast 's answer because he/she posted a code example that gave me a better idea.

Answer (score -3):

Please don't start your sentences with conjunctives.

> changes the page shown depending on the URL

Doesn't that happen with most web pages?

> access different "pages" using ?page=pageName

Oh - you mean by the query part of the URL - a front controller pattern - yeuch!

> I can echo a PHP file onto a page but execute the PHP code inside the file as well.

Do you mean you want to see the PHP source code **and** the output of the code? Or just the output of the code?

In your front controller:

```
<?php
    if (realpath($_REQUEST['page'])!=$_REQUEST['page']) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
        die ("Naughty!");
    }
    $script=SOME_PATH . $_REQUEST['page'] . ".php";

    if (!file_exists($script) || !is_readable($script)) {
         header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
         die ("File not found");
    }
    print "src = <br />";
    highlight_file($script);
    print "<hr />Output:<br />";
    include($script);
```

Comment: Yeah, I wrote this post in a hurry (had to get out of the house for an event) and didn't do a quality check. I was hoping to get an answer by the time I got back, and I sure did! :)
Thanks for the constructive criticism. I really appreciate it.